# Require node-opcua in electron freezes the electron instance

Tags: javascript, electron, node-opcua

Electron freezes when [node-opcua](http://node-opcua.github.io/) is required in index.html and a process called Electron Helper takes up 100% of the cpu.

I have encountered the problem on macOS 10.14.2, but a friend tested in Windows 10 and that worked.

From package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.4"
},
"dependencies": {
    "node-opcua": "^0.5.6"
}
```

Main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Index.html

```
<script>
// Does not work
const opcua = require('node-opcua')
console.log(opcua)

// Works
// const fs = require('fs')
// console.log(fs)
</script>
```

When running the simple code it should just print the opcua object in the console. But the complete electorn process freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by updating node-opcua to 2.1.9 and electron to 6.0.11